# Use of array in mips to store user input and search

Tags: arrays, mips

I'm new to this mips program and I'm trying to write a program that the user choose the number of items that they want to have in an array (between 1-10) and then enter those values which we will store into our array.(note: user input is in bold and underlined) and one more question how do we search that the number is present in the array list or not?

```
.data
    prompt0:.asciiz "How many items will the list contain?"
    prompt: .asciiz "\n Enter a number between 1 to 10 : "
    prompt1: .asciiz "\n Enter the first value: "
    prompt2:.asciiz  "\n Enter the next value: "
    .align 4
    Array: .space 32

.text 
li $v0,4
la $a0,prompt0
syscall

while:
beq $t0,4,exit

li $v0,4
la $a0,prompt
syscall

li $v0,5
syscall

li $v0,4
la $a0,prompt1
syscall

li $v0,5
syscall

sw $v0,Array($t0)
addi $t0,$t0,4

j while

exit:
li $v0,4
la $a0,prompt2
syscall

li $v0,5
syscall

sw $v0,Array($t0)
addi $t0,$t0,4
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall


excepted output:
How many items will the list contain?
Enter a number between 1 and 10: 5
Enter the first value: 1
Enter the next value: 2
Enter the next value: 9
Enter the next value: 7
Enter the next value: 5
```

Comment: (1) `$t0` is uninitalized. (2) `syscall` 5 returns a value in `$v0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems other than the mentioned ones. Hard to even keep track on them. One of them is the placement of the `while` label. Why it is there? You will keep printing the `prompt` string this way.

Also searching for an item is not that hard just iterate over the array and use for example `sub` to determine if the current array element is equal to the searched for number, because in that case their difference will be 0.

Rather then trying to list all the problems I show you how I made it work (Note: It most likely not the optimal way, but will get the job done)

```
.data
    prompt0:.asciiz "How many items will the list contain?"
    prompt: .asciiz "\n Enter a number between 1 to 10 : "
    prompt1: .asciiz "\n Enter the first value: "
    prompt2:.asciiz  "\n Enter the next value: "
    prompt3:.asciiz  "\n Enter the value to search for: "
    search_success:.asciiz  "The array contains the number"
    search_fail:.asciiz  "The array does not contains the number"

.align 4
    Array: .space 32

.text 

### prompt to ask for the number of items
li $v0,4
la $a0,prompt0
syscall

li $v0,4
la $a0,prompt
syscall

### read in the # of items
li $v0,5
syscall

move $t1, $v0 # save the # of items
move $t4, $v0 # save the # of items to use it in search also

### if the # of items is outside the [1,10] range then terminate program
bge $t1, 11, end 
ble $t1, 0, end

### loading in the Array start address
la $t0, Array

### prompt for 1st value
li $v0,4
la $a0,prompt1
syscall

### read in the first value
li $v0,5
syscall

### save first value and advancing the pointer
sw $v0,($t0)
addi $t0,$t0,4

### decrease the # of items need to be read in
sub $t1,$t1,1

### branch to the end of the read in loop to skip it since array has only 1 element
beq $t1, 0, end_loop

loop:
#### prompt for next item
li $v0,4
la $a0,prompt2
syscall

### read in next item
li $v0,5
syscall

### save the read in value to array
sw $v0,($t0)
addi $t0,$t0,4

### decrease the # of items need to be read in
sub $t1,$t1,1
bne $t1, 0, loop
end_loop:
###########################################
### Search in the array for given value ###
###########################################

### prompt for the number to search for
li $v0,4
la $a0,prompt3
syscall

### read in the number
li $v0,5
syscall

### load Array start address
la $t0, Array

search_loop:
lb $t2, ($t0) # load in the current Array element
sub $t3, $t2, $v0 # *Array - searched_number
beq $t3, 0, found_num # if the result 0 meaning they are equal -> branch
addi $t0, $t0, 4 # if not then advance the Array pointer
subi $t4, $t4, 1 # decrease the number of items remaining 
beq $t4, 0, do_not_found_num # if no more item remain -> the number is not in the array
b search_loop # loop

found_num:
### print succes string
li $v0,4
la $a0,search_success
syscall
b end

do_not_found_num:
### print fail string
li $v0,4
la $a0,search_fail
syscall
b end

end:
li $v0,10
syscall
```

Comment: Thank you both for your help and i will work hard to be familiar with this language.